# How do i send a Firebase Push Notification via java instead of the FirebaseConsole?

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting into Firebase Cloud Messaging, and i would like to know how to send a message in a Push Notification with java code, instead of manually writing it in the Firebase Console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option at the moment is to call the REST API for Firebase Cloud Messaging from your Java code.

The REST API is covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message. You'll also want to read about [authenticating the request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server), which includes a Java sample.

If you can't get it working from those yet, also have a look at some of the [previous questions about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D+send+from+java).

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add dependency... 
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'


private String strServerKey = "Your server key";
private String strAuthorization = "key=" + strServerKey;

//Put JSON data...

JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
jsonMain.put("to", token);

JSONObject jsonNotification = new JSONObject();
jsonNotification.put("title", "Notification Title");
jsonNotification.put("body", "Notification Body");
jsonMain.put("notification", jsonNotification);

JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
jsonData.put("title", "Data Payload Title");
jsonData.put("body", "Data Payload Body");
jsonMain.put("data", jsonData);

String sendJsonData=jsonMain.toString();


StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, strFcmUrl,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       //
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() {
        return sendJsonData.getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        params.put("Authorization", strAuthorization);
        return params;
    }
};
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);




public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    private static Context context;
    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
    private static AppController mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it in python using the api key and the mobile token.
In java, I believe you can do something like this

```
public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "xyxyxyxxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy";
public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

// userDeviceIdKey is the device id you will query from your database

public static void pushFCMNotification(String userDeviceIdKey) throws Exception{

   String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM; // You FCM AUTH key
   String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM; 

   URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   conn.setUseCaches(false);
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setDoOutput(true);

   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+authKey);
   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   json.put("to",userDeviceIdKey.trim());
   JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
   info.put("title", "Notificatoin Title"); // Notification title
   info.put("body", "Hello Test notification"); // Notification body
   json.put("notification", info);

   OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
   wr.write(json.toString());
   wr.flush();
   conn.getInputStream();
}
```

[See](https://lhe.io/fcm-push-notification-server-side-integration/)

For my python implementation i used `from pyfcm import FCMNotification` library.
[See](https://github.com/akshaybahadur21/PythonServer_WristbandModule/blob/master/project.py)